# get every two card combination from subset of standard deck

Tags: java, performance, poker

I have a standard deck of cards and then have removed a few, from the remaining cards I want to calculate all of the possible two card combinations. For example with 47 cards there is 47 choose 2 combinations. Can anyone think of an efficient way to do this other than

```
foreach(card){
  combinations.add(card, card +1)
}
```

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
for(int i=0; i<47; i++) {
  for(int j=i+1; j<47; j++) {
     combinations.add(i, j);
  }
}
```

This is the most efficient way, as it goes through each pair only once.

If you just want the *number* of two-pair combinations, see [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Combination).

Answer (score 1):

[On this site](http://www.java-forum.org/codeschnipsel-u-projekte/81973-combinatorics.html) there are some algorithms solving combinatoric problems. Look for a class called

```
class ChoiceIterable<T> implements Iterable<T[]>
```

Answer (score 1):

If all you need is just two card subsets (as opposed to a variable number), you could easily do this with two nested for loops.

```
for(i=0;i<cards.length;i++){
   for(j=i+1;j<cards.length;j++){
      combinations.add(cards[i],cards[j]);
   }
}
```